# What do these exec su parameters do?

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, upstart, init

What is the meaning of the switches and parameters of this command?

```
exec su -s /bin/sh -c 'exec "$0" "$@"' root -- /opt/nsq/bin/nsqd
```

Specifically the `--` part and what `exec "$0" "$@"` is supposed to do.

I know `$0` sets a loop for the script to keep running.

You can ignore the `/opt/nsq/bin/nsqd` part. This is the app I'm running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
exec
```

The command it runs, *su*, replaces the shell without creating a new process.

```
sudo -s /bin/sh -c
```

The substitute user runs the specified shell, /bin/sh and executes the following command.

```
exec "$0" "$@"
```

Run command `$0` , the name of the script, (your first variable, i.e., `/opt/nsq/bin/nsqd` )

```
"$@"
```

with all the arguments, using the appropriate quoting

```
--
```

The double hyphens delimit the option list. Everything following, even if they begin with a hypen, are considered to be operands.  For example, `sort -- -r` reads from the file named `-r` instead of trying to use '-r' as an option.

Comment: You're awesome. I get the picture and it really helped, but i have a few more small questions. In this case, when it runs inside an init script, I won't have to use this unless the init script itself gets parameters from outside? And just one more thing, which i find a bit difficult to understand
Whenever I use -- it's for scripting purposes mostly and basically just ignores any parameters after it?
So why would I want to use it? I can just never use parameters. And does this -- parameter is called? i couldn't find something really informative about it. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the follow through. If you have further questions about this issue, please click on the 'edit' link below the original question and revise that original question, as per the House Rules here. That way, your question gets improved and refined, and when others look at it, they will better understand the issue at hand.